# Current Location and custom map pin image in market

Tags: ios, mapkit

i know this question is asked thousand of time, and i had searched a lot and applied many codes but it doesn't worked. I have mapkit under  it there is a button to show the current location but when i click it it shows nothing and i have set my own custom image for map pin but it also doesn't show, my code is

For current location,

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{


 NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{


 NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    NSString *longi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"Longi %@",longi);
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSLog(@"Longi %@",lat);
}
}
```

My code for custom *Map* pin image is this,

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
MKAnnotationView *view=[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annoView"];
if (!view) {
    view=[[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annoView"];
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }else{
    view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"car_marker.png"];
        view.canShowCallout=YES;
    }
}

return view;
}
```

Comment: Did you call `addAnnotation` method?

Comment: yes check in my code. @KosukeOgawa

Comment: I could not find `addAnnotation ` in your code ;-(

Comment: look at the method for MKAnnotationview at the end. @KosukeOgawa

Comment: I think you should call `[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];` in didUpdateToLocation.

Comment: i have to write this in viewDidload method? @KosukeOgawa

Comment: I added answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `addAnnotation` in didUpdateToLocation.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: How can i use my own custom image instead of default pin. @Kosuke Ogawa

Comment: Did you write `self.mapView.delegate = self;` in viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Don' t forget `@interface YourViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

Comment: Yup , i have written both of them but still not working. @Kosuke Ogawa

Comment: Mmm, your code looks like correct... How about `[UIImage imageNamed:@"car_marker"]` ? (removed ".png")

Comment: This is the custom image that i want to use instead of default pin. @ Kosuke Ogawa